# convert string to smtpclient in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I am currently developing an asp.net web app. I have a class which is going to be used for sending an email.

I want to get the SMTP Server address from a MySQL Database. To get the value from the MySQL Database I am using

```
string smtp = reader.GetString("smtp_server");
```

For assigning the smtp server to the mail function I am using

```
SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient(smtp);
```

Hoever, I am getting the error unable to convert from string to SmtpClient. I have tried to add a cast of (SmtpClient) but it is not letting me do this.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you sure that error points exactly to these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the error is happening where you think it's happening.  The `SmtpClient` class has [a constructor which accepts a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0y6s613.aspx).  I get the feeling there's more happening in your code than you're sharing with us.  Can you show us more code?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your help. I had the string and the smtpclient variable called the same thing. Both of your comments made me notice so thanks.

Comment: @Boardy: Glad I could help, even indirectly.  Sometimes it's just a matter of getting a second set of eyes on the code to see something :)